# XML deserialization attempt yields empty object

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xml-deserialization

I am trying to deserialize some XML in a console app. I only care about some of the data, so I created a class with just the fields that I need. The program runs, but the PetFinderPetRecord that I deserialize to has all empty members (all strings are null and all ints are 0).

Here is the XML:

```
<petfinder xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://api.petfinder.com/schemas/0.9/petfinder.xsd">
<header>
<version>0.1</version>
<timestamp>2014-10-23T04:12:37Z</timestamp>
<status>
<code>100</code>
<message/>
</status>
</header>
<pet>
<id>29165893</id>
<shelterId>VA72</shelterId>
<shelterPetId/>
<name>Buckeye and Hawkeye</name>
<animal>Cat</animal>
<breeds>
<breed>Domestic Short Hair-black</breed>
</breeds>
<mix>no</mix>
<age>Baby</age>
<sex>M</sex>
<size>M</size>
<options>
<option>hasShots</option>
<option>altered</option>
<option>housetrained</option>
</options>
<description>
<![CDATA[
Buckeye and Hawkeye are about 6 months old as of 5/6/14. Buckeye and his brother, Hawkeye, are very bonded and hope to find a home together. They are very playful and love to have their chin scratched. They get along very well with other cats and are curious and lovable. They will make a wonderful addition to your family. Please email jleach1234@aol.com for more information.
]]>
</description>
<lastUpdate>2014-05-07T21:30:42Z</lastUpdate>
<status>A</status>
<media>
<photos>
<photo id="1" size="pnt">
http://photos.petfinder.com/photos/pets/29165893/1/?bust=1399498241&width=60&-pnt.jpg
</photo>
<photo id="1" size="fpm">
http://photos.petfinder.com/photos/pets/29165893/1/?bust=1399498241&width=95&-fpm.jpg
</photo>
<photo id="1" size="x">
http://photos.petfinder.com/photos/pets/29165893/1/?bust=1399498241&width=500&-x.jpg
</photo>
<photo id="1" size="pn">
http://photos.petfinder.com/photos/pets/29165893/1/?bust=1399498241&width=300&-pn.jpg
</photo>
<photo id="1" size="t">
http://photos.petfinder.com/photos/pets/29165893/1/?bust=1399498241&width=50&-t.jpg
</photo>
<photo id="2" size="pnt">
http://photos.petfinder.com/photos/pets/29165893/2/?bust=1399498241&width=60&-pnt.jpg
</photo>
<photo id="2" size="fpm">
http://photos.petfinder.com/photos/pets/29165893/2/?bust=1399498241&width=95&-fpm.jpg
</photo>
<photo id="2" size="x">
http://photos.petfinder.com/photos/pets/29165893/2/?bust=1399498241&width=500&-x.jpg
</photo>
<photo id="2" size="pn">
http://photos.petfinder.com/photos/pets/29165893/2/?bust=1399498241&width=300&-pn.jpg
</photo>
<photo id="2" size="t">
http://photos.petfinder.com/photos/pets/29165893/2/?bust=1399498241&width=50&-t.jpg
</photo>
</photos>
</media>
<contact>
<address1>PO Box 7040</address1>
<address2/>
<city>Fairfax Station</city>
<state>VA</state>
<zip>22039</zip>
<phone>(703) 940-9183</phone>
<fax/>
<email>Jleach1234@aol.com</email>
</contact>
</pet>
</petfinder>
```

Here is the console code:

```
public class Class1
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string URL = "http://api.petfinder.com/pet.getRandom";
        string urlParameters = "?key=myprivatekey&id=ID123&status=A&format=xml&output=full";

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(URL);

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
        new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));

        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(urlParameters).Result;
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            XmlRootAttribute xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute();
            xRoot.ElementName = "petfinder";
            xRoot.IsNullable = true;
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PetFinderPetRecord), xRoot);

            PetFinderPetRecord record = null;

            using (Stream stream = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result)
            {
                record = (PetFinderPetRecord)serializer.Deserialize(stream); // <-- has empty members
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", (int)response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the class I'm trying to deserialize to:

```
[Serializable()]
public class PetFinderPetRecord
{
    [XmlElement("id")]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("shelterId")]
    public int shelterId { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("shelterPetId")]
    public int shelterPetId { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("animal")]
    public string animal { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("mix")]
    public string mix { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("age")]
    public string age { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("sex")]
    public string sex { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("size")]
    public string size { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("description")]
    public string description { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("lastupdate")]
    public DateTime lastupdate { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("status")]
    public string status;

    public PetFinderPetRecord()
    {

    }
}
```

If someone could show me what I'm missing or what I'm doing wrong, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please edit your code example so that it's a good, concise-but-complete code example that reliably reproduces the problem (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This is the least amount of code I can provide to reproduce the problem. I provided all of the XML and the class I want to deserialize to for completeness.

Comment: It is simply not possible that that is actually the least amount of code that can reproduce the problem. So if you can't provide less, a good exercise for you would be to learn how to trim the code example. Also, it's almost certain your bug can be demonstrated without actually querying a web server, so in that respect there is _more_ code here than is necessary. Again, please see the link I referenced about how to provide an "MCVE" (in SO jargon).

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is the only problem, but on this line of code:

```
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(urlParameters).Result;
```

you should await the call:

```
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(urlParameters).Result;
```

otherwise your if statement could execute before there is a server response

note: to do this, you also need to add the async keyword to your method declaration

```
static void async Main(string[] args)
```

I hope this helps

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion and I tried it out. I created a new method called `getData()` instead of putting `async` on `Main` (because I got an error saying that `async` cannot be used on an entry point). I also made the other change you suggested on the `HttpResponseMessage`. Now when I debug, when I step over that line (F10), execution stops. I also wrapped the code in a try catch block, but no exceptions are thrown. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I have updated `getData()` to return a `Task` and now I call it from `Main()` this way: `get().Wait()` The method returns now, but the object is still empty. Does anyone have any further suggestions?

Comment: what response code are you getting from the server?
I reduced your code to just the xml deserialization step and had it try and deserialize the xml file that you gave in your question and it threw an InvalidOperation exception when it reached the 38th line, 68th character (the - in the URL)

Comment: Thank you for continuing to look into this with me. The `StatusCode` is 200, the `ReasonPhrase` is 'OK' and `IsSuccessStatusCode` is `true`.

Comment: I ran the XML through a validator (http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp) and it says "error on line 38 at column 74: EntityRef: expecting ';'". It looks like I'll need to manipulate the XML before trying to deserialize it.